# A function's limit gives infinity symbol with tilde

Tags: calculus, limits, notation

I made a function while studying some unsolved problem ($3x+1$ problem) and wanted to find a function's limit. Im no well educated mathematician so I used Symbolab with L'Hopital's rule. I got this strange infinity symbol:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \tilde{\infty}$$

What does the infinity with the tilde above symbol means? (in context to limits).
I read that some function approaches this complex infinity. But, what do one do when one gets such an result. Is it related to the Riemann Sphere? Is the Collatz Conjecture related to the Riemann Sphere, or am I out on a blueberry trip?

Comment: I cannot begin to guess what it means, but/and, if it's any comfort to you, I'd not seen this notation until just now, either, reading your post.

Comment: That's typical used to denote complex infinity
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexInfinity.html#:~:text=Complex%20infinity%20is%20an%20infinite,to%20represent%20complex%20infinity.

Comment: I would not have expected a more fitting person to answer this @infinitylord

Comment: I don't know how Symbolab works, but if you're dividing by something that approaches zero (especially if without specifying a direction along which it does so) then this would be a typical result.

Comment: Perhaps there is documentation for Symbolab where the explanation is found.

Comment: Doesn't Mathematica use this symbol for complex (undirected) infinity? Perhaps Symbolab does too.

Answer (score 1):

The symbol $\tilde\infty$ is used, somewhat confusingly, for a few different things in different contexts. It can mean:

- the point at infinity on the Riemann sphere (or [one-point compactification of $\Bbb R$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectively_extended_real_line) in contexts where $\infty$ would otherwise denote "positive infinity")
- an unspecified [directed infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_infinity) in the complex plane (or in $\Bbb R^n$, if you're a terrible person)
- a directed infinity in the complex plane whose real part is nonnegative (I've only seen this once, and I don't think it's common)

I'm no math historian, but I've seen older textbooks use $\tilde{(\cdot)}$ to indicate that a variable represents a complex number. Based on that, I would guess that $\tilde\infty$ was used - at least at some point - to indicate divergence of complex valued functions (as opposed to the more familiar $-\infty,+\infty$ that appears in e.g. Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*).

As for what $\tilde\infty$ means in Symbolab, specifically: I have no idea. I don't know how Symbolab works, and there doesn't seem to be any kind of documentation.